# Counting hits from multiple conditions

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm storing swimming competitions results in elasticsearch to be able to analyse and present data in different ways. Each result is stored as a separate document, time in millis. Like this:

```
{
  "swimmer": "xyz123",
  "stroke": "butterfly",
  "distance": 25,
  "time": 20250
}
```

However, for younger swimmers there's an award when they achieve certain times in the five different event types (different strokes) and I would like to be able to find all swimmers who have a time lower than a specified time in all of the five events (different time for different events).

Example: 
Middle Cup Award is received when a swimmer have completed:
- 50m backstroke in 47 seconds or less
- 50m free (crawl) in 31 seconds or less
- 50m breast stroke in 51 seconds or less
- 25m butterfly in 22 seconds or less
- 100m medley in 1m40s or less.

I've tried to use a bool/should query consisting of a bool/must query for each of the limits per stroke. On this I have aggregations (term aggregation) on Swimmer -> Stroke and can based on the bucket count determine if a swimmer have reached the level in 5 strokes.

However, this returns a bucket for all swimmers who've reached any of the limits, and even though it's not a huge amount of swimmers (yet), I find this won't work in the long term.

Am I missing something (having bad luck thinking)? Could anyone recommend how to achieve this in a single query?

Simplified query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        { //* backstroke, 50m, <47000ms *// },
        { //* freestroke, 50m, <41000ms *// },
        { //* breaststroke, 50m, <51000ms *// },
        { //* butterfly, 25m, <22000ms *// },
        { //* medley, 100m, <100000ms *// }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "by_swimmer": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "swimmer"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "by_stroke": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "stroke"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I might be missing something, but wouldn't changing the "should" to a "must" take care of it? I'll try populating a test index later to try it out.

Comment: @JoeZack the should contains one combo of three bool/must conditions per event type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query returns any document that is matching a single or more should clauses. 
You are creating a bucket containing all documents of a single swimmer, then you are dividing those documents per stroke type. Because your initial query result contains all documents matching any award you will end up with the result you described.
There are multiple approaches to handle this.

1. You do a seperate query for every award, containing the filter query in a must clause. This ensures only documents matching the award filter are selected.
2. You change your query to select all document e.g. do a [match all](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-all-query.html). Then you handle your logic in the aggregations. You keep the terms aggregation on swimmer to get all documents matching a single swimmer in one bucket. Then you do nested [filter aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html) on the swimmer level for every award, if they contain any documents the swimmer has completed the award.

Example for 2:

```
{
  "query" : {
    "match_all" : {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "by_swimmer": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "swimmer"
      },
    "aggs": {
      "stroke_award": {
        "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [{ //* backstroke, 50m, <47000ms *// }]
          }
        }
      },
      "freestroke_award": {
        "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [ { //* freestroke, 50m, <41000ms *// }]
            }
          }
        },
        "breaststroke_award": {
          "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [ { //* breaststroke, 50m, <51000ms *// }]
            }
          }
        },
        "butterfly_award": {
          "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [ { //* butterfly, 25m, <22000ms *// }]
            }
          }
        },
          "medley_award": {
          "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [ { //* medley, 100m, <100000ms *// }]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When there is a document in one of those buckets, the award is completed for the swimmer.

Comment: Thanks for your response! In this case the psuedo-query contains the conditions for one award. I need to use `should` to get all results which qualifies a swimmer for the award. I like your second bullet though, I'll try and see if I can get that working better.

Comment: When i have time today i will try to edit my answer to provide an example for it.

Comment: @user2435850 i updated my answer with an document, i dont have a running elastic instance to test it sadly.

Comment: Ah, filter buckets. Should've thought about that. Thanks!